# VB.Net Run Code When WinForm Application Exits From Anywhere

Tags: vb.net, winforms, event-handling, exit, handles

I have a quick question.

I want to run some come when my application exits, wherever in the winform application it may be. The reason is that the user adds/changes data in the application in different forms, and I have it set to save different data to My.Settings. When the application exits, I want it all to be saved to a text file, to be loaded when the application is next started up. I cannot save to text file whenever the data is changed because it is changing too many times, so for ease of access, I save it My.Settings.
I know how to save the data to a text file, I just want to know how can I have it run the code to save data to the text file WHEN the application is exiting.

Comment: VB saves MySettings when the app is shutting down by default.  Project Properties -> Application.  Are you after something different?

Comment: I am trying to make the application portable. I understand My.Settings is saved on the computer, not to the application. I want it to be portable, so everything is saved to the text file and My.Settings is cleared. I am only using My.Settings to make it easier to change and save data.

Comment: in that case, there is an Application Shutdown event where you could save the values. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/036kk0as(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks, I can't choose it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB allows you to add code to perform tasks when your application Starts or Shuts down.  To access these, go to **Project Properties -> Application** Click **"View Application Events"**.

This will open a file very much like a form code window.  From the left/Declarations menu select **MyApplication Events**, then select **ShutDown** from the event list.  This will bring up this:

```
Private Sub MyApplication_Shutdown(sender As Object, 
             e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shutdown
  ' your code
  ' to executes when the application is shutting down

End Sub
```